# Unable to get objects to collide

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, collision, bounding-box

For the life of me, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  I have managed to make a player and make it shoot.  I've also managed to make balls spawn in at random locations/speeds in the picture box.

I can't get any `Collision` to work.  I am trying to keep all balls in the picture box and bounce back and also bounce off each other, and then destroy them when shot.

I have been trying to use `Ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds)`, but it seems that `Ball.bounds` is wrong.

I have a vague idea why it is wrong but not definitive.  My property bounds in `box.cs` is either wrong or I don't know how to make that relate to positioning all my balls.

A little nudge in the right direction would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this issue for a while now.

---

*ball.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace shootyarcher
{
    class Ball : Box
    {
        public string bounds { get; set; }

        static private Random generator = new Random();
        private int countdown;

        public Ball ()
        {
            pic = Properties.Resources.Balloon;
            x = generator.Next(60, 1920);
            y = generator.Next(100, 1000);
            xspeed = generator.Next(-10, 4);
            yspeed = generator.Next(-10, 4);
            countdown = generator.Next(100, 200);
        }
        public new void Move() 
        {
            countdown--;
            if (countdown == 0)
            {
                xspeed = generator.Next(-4, 4);
                yspeed = generator.Next(-4, 4);
                countdown = generator.Next(20, 40);
            }
            x = x + xspeed;
            y = y + yspeed;
        }
    }
}
```

---

*box.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing; //pictures

namespace shootyarcher
{
    class Box
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float w;
        public float h;
        public float xspeed;
        public float yspeed;
        public Image pic;

        public Box() // constructor
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            xspeed = 0;
            yspeed = 0;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            x = x + xspeed;
            y = y + yspeed;
        }

        public void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage (pic, x, y);
        }

        public float Width()
        {
            return pic.Width;
        }

        public float Height()
        {
            return pic.Height;
        }

        public float Left()
        {
            return x;
        }

        public float Right()
        {
            return x + Width();
        }

        public float Top()
        {
            return y;
        }

        public float Bottom()
        {
            return y + Height();
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Form1.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace shootyarcher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Archer player;
        List<Arrow> Shiv;
        List<Ball> Kill;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Cursor.Hide();

            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;


            player = new Archer(0, 0);
            Shiv = new List<Arrow>();
            Kill = new List<Ball>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                Ball temp = new Ball();
                Kill.Add(temp);
            }

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Move();
            foreach (Arrow t in Shiv)
            {
                t.Move();
            }
            foreach (Ball m in Kill)
            {
                m.Move();
            }

            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                player.moveup = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                player.movedown = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                Arrow temp = new Arrow(player.x, player.y);
                Shiv.Add(temp);
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                player.moveup = false;
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                player.movedown = false;
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            player.Draw(e.Graphics);
            foreach (Arrow t in Shiv)
            {
                t.Draw(e.Graphics);
            }
            foreach (Ball m in Kill)
            {
                m.Draw(e.Graphics);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your `Move()` method pick a random direction constantly?

Comment: i did that to make it more challenging to shoot, they randomly pick a direction and speed.

Comment: I don't see any collision code in the code you've posted (apart from the initial comment about IntersectsWith) and there's no reference to Bounds in either of Box or Ball yet you say you use Ball.Bounds! I do see `this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` this seems to be setting the bounds of the current form to the entire display. Is this what was intended? Maybe just post the code that is causing the issue and any set up code it requires. I'm assuming that you're using separate PictureBoxes for each graphical item you wish to collide.